# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'latest_comments_list' referenced before assig nment

Tags: python, django

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    latest_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {'latest_articles_list': **strong text**latest_articles_list})

def detail(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
    except:
        raise Http404("статья не найдена")

        latest_comments_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comments_list': latest_comments_list})

def leave_comment(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
    except:
        raise Http404("статья не найдена")

    a.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'], comment_text = request.POST['text'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('articles:detail', args = (a.id,)) )
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'latest_comments_list' referenced before assig
nment

Comment: @bemaybe There is an obvious indentation error. Please check carefully before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `detail` function. latest_comments_list is in the `except` block. So if the `Article` object is successfully retrieved, `latest_comments_list` will not be set. As an extra note, it is good practice specify which exception you're catching in the `except`. Try this:

```py
def detail(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("статья не найдена")

    latest_comments_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comments_list': latest_comments_list})
```